# Symfony - FOSUser Bundle Styling Form Elements

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to add classes to style some of the form elements FOSUser Bundle uses... 
for example ;

I want to style `{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}` in a twig that i use.

how do i add styling to this call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, be sure to understand how to [customize form elements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Next, as described in [FosuserBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) , you will need to create a bundle that extends FosuserBundle like that

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle;


use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

FosuserBundle will now look into your resources

**EDIT:**

To update your form element class

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'myformclass'} }) }}
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i've already done all of that. I have a full project running already with extended and overriden bundles, etc.. My question is just adding styling to the form elements.. 
For custom forms, you can just use {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }} which resolves into a text box. i want to apply a css class to it. So when it resolves, it will show something like this.. <input type="Text" class="XYZ"......

Comment: i also added a similar question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741084/fosuser-bundle-adding-placeholder-to-form-element-symfony .. if you know how to do this, I would really appreciate your response.. thanks