# FOSUser Bundle Adding PlaceHolder to form element

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I understand that when you are overriding FOSUser Bundle Forms, you follow this structure;

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'myformclass'} }) }}
```

I also want to add PlaceHolder option to my form element.. How can i do that?

so it will look like something like this;

```
<input class="myformclass" placeholder="Password" type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'myformclass', 'placeholder': 'Password', 'id': password'}}) }}
```

Field name depends on your form name

it will like be named this for fosuser bundle register form

```
fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][password]
```

the id will be

```
fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_password
```

You can override "id" like written in my example

Required and name options are defined in the form class

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [placeholder attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder).

### METHOD 1: Twig

```twig
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'enter your password'} }) }}
```

### METHOD 2: Form Builder

```php
$builder
    ->add('plainPassword', null , array(
        'attr'=> 
            array('placeholder'=>'enter your password')
        )
    );
```